# Creating Subscription for Microsoft Graph API: Subscription validation request failed

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, fastapi

I try to create a Subscription for Microsoft Graph API. However, I get the error

> Subscription validation request failed. Response must exactly match validationToken query parameter.

The Validation Request looks as follows :

> POST /?validationToken=Validation%3a+Testing+client+application+reachability+for+subscription+Request-Id%3a+c69b04df-f3d3-411c-8ceb-7f1ad8b7a927 HTTP/1.1

Using FastApi, the API where validation request is sent to look like

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/")
def read_call_record(validationToken):
    data = {"validationToken": validationToken}
    return data
```

The returned data variable looks like:

> {'validationToken': 'Validation: Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: c69b04df-f3d3-411c-8ceb-7f1ad8b7a927'}

Can someone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the awnser myself. Here function that works:

```
@app.post("/")
def read_call_record(validationToken):
    return Response(content=validationToken, media_type='text/plain')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code needs to Url Decode the `validationToken` query parameter and return it back to Graph.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#notification-endpoint-validation), your response must happen within 10 seconds with the following properties:

> - A status code of `HTTP 200 OK`.
> - A content type of `text/plain`.
> - A body that includes the **URL decoded** validation token. Simply reflect back the same string that was sent in the `validationToken` query parameter.
>
> Important: If the client returns an encoded validation token, the validation will fail.

Comment: THX for the answer. However, I am not sure what you mean by URL decoding. Can you give an answer and how the return in my read_call_record should look like?

Comment: I added the current output. I think there is something wrong here